# Receive data from $scope in script block

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet

I have spent more than 3 hours in research, and still haven't found the answer. I researched these:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

https://habrahabr.ru/post/277087/

http://metanit.com/web/angular/2.14.php

and dozens of other topics in StackOverflow.

The question is: I built a Javascript page with Leaflet and Angular. And I need access to data in HTML block and script.

The last 4 lines are causing my problem. I am trying to receive data from `$scope` for next functions.

```
var myApp=angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp.controller('pointController', function($scope) {

        $scope.points = [{
            id: 0,
            lat: 55.467,
            lang: 44.276
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            lat: 56.467,
            lang: 47.276

        },
        {
            id: 2,
            lat: 58.467,
            lang: 48.276

        }
    ]
});

var elem = angular.element(document.querySelector(".length"));
var minElem = elem.find('span');

var x=myApp.controller.$scope.points[0].id;

var y=angularModule.points[0].id;
```

Furthermore I want to use this data in functions like this, instead of `matrix`:

```
 L.marker([matrix[0][1], matrix[0][2]]).addTo(map)
            .bindPopup("<strong>One</strong><br />Alone marker "+ matrix[0][0]).openPopup();
```

Comment: Suggest you use angular leaflet module and follow api in that module

Comment: Can You show, or give link for example? i m study http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/#!/examples/events , but this not exectly, wat i need.

Answer (score 0):

The `$scope.points` is accessible in your DOM via `points`. You can for example show them like:

```
<li ng-repeat="point in points">
  {{point.id}}, {{point.lat}}, {{point.lang}}
</li>
```

Or in your controller, if you want to add all points to your map:

```
for (var i in $scope.points) {
   L.market($scope.points[i].lat, $scope.points[i].lang).addTo(map)
}
```

Your 2 last lines of code while calculating `x` and `y` don't make sense at all.

Please take a look to this angular Leaflet directive to be used in your angular app. It will make everything much easier. https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive

Comment: I use it in DOM. Like you write. But i need this data in script block.

Comment: What do you mean in `script block` ?

Comment: i need to change L.marker([matrix[0][1], matrix[0][2]]).addTo(map) to something like: L.market($scope.point.lat, $scope.point.lang).addTo(map)